# Show by induction, that $\mu(T^{k}A\Delta A)=0~\forall~k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: induction, ergodic-theory

Here are some definitions that might be necessary for my following question:

**(I)** The Quadruple $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu,T)$ is called dynamical system, if $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a probability space and $ T\colon\Omega\to\Omega$ a measurable Transformation with the property $\mu\circ T^{-1}=\mu$.

**(II)** A set $A\in\mathcal{A}$ is called $T$-invariant, if $T^{-1}(A)=A $ a.s. (i.e. $T^{-1}(A)\Delta A$ is a null set).

**(III)** The system $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu,T)$ is called ergodic, if for all T-invariant sets $A\in\mathcal{A}$ it is $\mu(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$.

> > Assume that $A\in\mathcal{A}$ is $T$-invarant, i.e. $\mu(T^{-1}A\Delta A)=0$. Show per induction that $\mu(T^{k}A\Delta A)=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Unfortunately, I do have some problems to do that.

The beginning is clear: For $k=-1$ it is (because $A$ is $T$-invariant
$$
\mu(T^{-1}A\Delta A)=0.
$$

Now assume that the statement is correct for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. It is to show, that 
$$
\mu(T^{k+1}A\Delta A)=0.
$$

I do not know how to do that. Can you please help me to show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for any measurable sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ that 
$$A\Delta C\subset (A\Delta B)\cup (B\Delta C),$$
hence for each $k\geqslant 0$, 
$$\mu(T^{-(k+1)}(A)\Delta A)\leqslant \mu(T^{-(k+1)}(A)\Delta T^{-k}A)+\mu(T^{-k}(A)\Delta A)=\mu(T^{-1}(A)\Delta A)+\mu(T^{-k}(A)\Delta A,$$
where the last inequality follows from the fact that $T$ preserves the measure $\mu$.

Comment: What I see is, that (because $T$ preserves $\mu$) $\mu(T^{-(k+1)}(A))=\mu(T^{-1}(A))$ and $\mu(T^{-k}(A))=\mu(A)$. But why is then $\mu(T^{-(k+1)}(A)\Delta T^{-k}(A))=\mu(T^{-1}(A)\Delta A)$?

Comment: Show that if $A$ and $B$ are measurable subsets, then $T^{-1}(A\Delta B)=(T^{-1}A)\Delta (T^{-1}B)$.

Comment: With that I get $\mu(T^{-(k+1)}(A)\Delta T^{-k}(A))=\mu(T^{-1}(T^{-k}(A))\Delta T^{-1}(T^{-(k-1)}(A))=\mu(T^{-1}(T^{-k}(A)\Delta T^{-(k-1)}(A))=\mu(T^{-k}(A)\Delta T^{-(k-1)}(A))$

Comment: ok, when doing this $k$-times, it is $\mu(T^{-1}(A)\Delta A)$.

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Thanks a lot!